# Restoring the new Windows 11 context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, context-menu

Awhile back I did a registry hack (don't remember what it was ) to stop using the new Windows 11 context menu.

1. How can I restore the new context menu?
2. How can I subsequently disable the new context menu?

See:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7cshxcppujr0dq2g03uio/ContextMenu.mp4?rlkey=ynbs0qiueehwgk1d8inf45i9t&dl=0

Comment: [This](https://techdows.com/2021/10/disable-or-enable-windows-11-new-context-menu.html) was my first search result, would post an answer, but I am on 17 hours without sleep

Comment: @Ramhound Thank it awesome. Just tried it. Reverted to old one again!  The problem with the new one is that I visually watch it add all the extra items at the bottom like onedrive, dropbox, tortoisgit, and tortoisesvn. Ugly.

Comment: So long as One Drive and Dropbox are properly connected, Windows 11 Context Menu is not slow. It may be the registry changes that now causes the slowness.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The Win11 version is meant to be a shortcut context menu with the most commonly used options shown - its purpose was never to replace the normal full context menus. To show the full context menu, `Shift`+Right-click _(this is why the Win11 context menu has at the bottom "Show more options", which does the same as `Shift`+Right-click)_

Comment: @JW0914 I know that. But by design the new menu shows this stated items and you can visually see it adding them ...

Comment: I do not think what you see is by design.  ! second or less for the main context and another second (max) for the "more" menu

Comment: @John Definitely much slower for me. And I had to disable a lot on context menu items because file explorer was crashing. Been getting fed up with it. When a menu shows I want it to be quick and I have a fast pc.

Comment: I have three Windows 11 Pro machines; all fast; and most definitely not slow. Also no issue with Windows Explorer

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Your issue isn't Win11's new context menu and is likely due to a 3rd-party context menu item - Sysinternals and Nirsoft both have utilities to disable context menu items to determine the cause - disable half, if it goes away, half of that, etc. until the problem one is found.

Comment: @JW0914 See the video (updated question)

Comment: Time to reinstall Windows. Problem described in the question seems different than the one in the video

Comment: When reinstalling Windows, upgrade ALL possible Apps to the 64-bit versions. 32-version of Apps using contexts conflict with Explorer in varying degrees. Stay away from registry changes - 95% not necessary to run Windows.

Comment: @John Yeah, but re-installing is like moving house. It will break some licenses. But fair enough.

Comment: I am well organized to be sure but I can be up and running in 8 hours.  Licenses kept in Key Pass.